# Is it possible to toggle a modal and open an URL in another tab at the same time when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have 4 buttons (`<a>` tags stylized to look like buttons), from which only two matter for this question:

- First one opens a link in another tab with its respective `href` value and with the `target="_blank"` attribute.
- Second one toggles a modal with some text fields to be manually filled with information inside the page at the URL linked in the first button.

I would like to open the same link from the first button by clicking the second one, but only the modal is shown and nothing else happens.

So far I've tried these options:

#### Option 1. Setting `href` and `target` equally for both buttons:

Left click toggles the modal only. Scroll wheel click opens the link in another tab and the modal is not shown.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button-1" href="some_url" target="_blank">Btn 1</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button-2" href="some_url" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal">Btn 2</a>
```

#### Option 2. Clicking button 1 from button 2 with jQuery code:

Left click on button 2 toggles the modal and the button 1 is clicked (I guess) since the line printed shows on the console.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button-1" href="some_url" target="_blank">Btn 1</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal">Btn 2</a>

$('#button-2').click(function(){
    $('#button-1').click();
});

$('#button-1').on('click', function(){
    console.log('Clicked ' + $(this).prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: not clear what you're aiming to do, further explanations would help us out.

Comment: My button 1 has a href set with, let's say, Wikipedia pages. And button 2 opens a modal where I would manually paste, let's say (again), the title of the Wikipedia page and the first paragraph. What I'm trying to do is to toggle the modal and open the link at the same time (as an usability shortcut if it helps).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using bootstrap.

```
$('#my-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#button-1').trigger('click');
});
```

Here you'll simulate the click when the modal is displayed.
Give it a try and tell me if it works

Comment: If he's using `BootStrap` he'll add it as a tag.

Comment: Yes, I'm using bootstrap. And with this solution it seems to have the same behavior as my option 2.

Comment: @ths yes, I'm using it and forgot to add the corresponding tag, sorry.

Comment: So it didn't open the link on a new tab ?

Answer (score 0):

You need avoid the default event of link and set your custom action

```
var openPage = function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 window.open(e.target.href,e.target.target)
}
```

Here you have a example using boostrap

[Code-pen snipet](https://codepen.io/horaa-moreno/pen/bxPXGr?editors=1010)